# Does there exist an $L$-function for any subset of $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, experimental-mathematics

Consider the following prime sum:

\begin{aligned}
\sum _{p}{\frac {\cos(x\log p)}{p^{1/2}}}
\end{aligned}

[image]

whose spikes appear at the Riemann $\zeta$ zeros as shown [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460561/does-this-partial-sum-over-primes-spike-at-all-zeta-zeros).

Taking these detected spikes (up to some partial sum), and denoting these approximated zeros as $t'$, the primes can be recovered with the sum:

\begin{aligned}
\sum _{n \in t'}{\frac {\cos(t'\log x)}{t'^{1/2}}}
\end{aligned}

[image]

albeit with added noise. Compare with the plot

\begin{aligned}
\sum _{n \in t}{\frac {\cos(t\log x)}{t^{1/2}}}
\end{aligned}

[image]

where $t$ is the imaginary part of the actual Riemann zeta zeros.

It turns out that it appears that this method can be used for any arbitrary integer sets

**e.g.**

*the set of twin primes:*

[image]

*the square numbers:*

[image]

Does this imply that there exists an $L$-function that corresponds to *any* subset of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Your title is redundant: Every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ah, yes!

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean with "correspondence". For any subset $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ you can consider the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n\in S}n^{-s}$ for instance. It will not be an "$L$-function" by most definitions of that term though.